# What is Line Height in css fonts?

Tags: css, fonts

Is line-height the padding above and blew the fonts?

I think it is like an up and down padding. When I use line-height property the padding up and down the fonts appears. Why use line height as we have padding up and down property?

Comment: Padding on a paragraph will only be added around the outside of the whole paragraph, rather than between lines, so if you want to spread lines of text apart, you need line-height.